# PDF em Reporting Service

Tags: pdf, reporting-services

Galera estou com um problema.

Estou utilizando o Visual Studio 2003 para gerar um relatório. Quando peço pra visualizar o relatório, aparece tudo certinho. O problema é quando mando gerar o PDF. Está disposicionando tudo. Alguem sabe de alguma configuração ou algo que possa estar dando esse conflito?

Agradeço

Comment: O Tamanho da página está A4?

Comment: Sim... O problema é que nao tem respeitado quebras de pagina e em alguns casos, o cabeçalho vai para o meio da pagina.

Comment: Não sei se é o problema, mas talvez usar uma versão mais recente, pois o Visual Studio está na Versão 2013. Já são 10 anos, pode ter algum Service Pack para o Visual Studio 2003 sem estar aplicado aí. http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=703